# Javascript test method not working ( as expected )

Tags: javascript, regex, performance

Regular expression

```
 [A-Za-z_-]+
```

should match strings that only have upper and lower case letters, underscores, and a dash

but when I run in chrome console

```
 /[A-Za-z_-]+/.test("johmSmith12")
```

Why it returns true

Comment: It returns true because it finds "johnSmith" (try here if you need a visual aid - http://refiddle.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't anchor the expression. You need to add `^` and `$`, which match beginning and end of string.

For example:

```
^[A-Za-z_-]+$
```

Just the `[A-Za-z_-]+` will match `johnSmith` in your example, leaving out the `12` (as  David Starkey pointed out).

Comment: I would rather prefer `\A` and `\Z`

Comment: @ted, JS doesn't have those. And it should be `\z` not `\Z` (in most flavors, PCRE included).

Answer (score 0):

It is due to your regex looking for *any* sequence of characters within the test string that matches the regex. In your example, `"johnSmith"` matches your regex criteria, and so `test` returns `true`.

If you instead put `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) at the ends of your regex, then you would assert that the *entire* string must match your regex:

```
/^[A-Za-z_-]+$/.test("johnSmith12");
```

This will return `false`.